# How does Phusion Passenger respect gemfiles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm wondering how it's possible to host multiple projects using different versions of Ruby and completely different gemsets. When I'm developing on my machine I use Bundler and chruby. But when serving production environment, can I use Bundler and chruby with Passenger either? How does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use different ruby version with Passenger. Look at this [section](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerRuby).

And, yes again, you can use different gemsets for you projects. Just instal them locally (see [--path](http://bundler.io/v1.8/bundle_install.html) argument). FYI: Capistrano install all gems locally (in `vendor/bundle` directory) by default.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's exactly what I've been looking for! One more question: I've seen people setting `passenger_ruby` path to their script invoking `chruby ruby-1.8.1; ruby`. Is it the right way to go? Is setting hard-coded path to `ruby` binary into Passenger's configuration file better?